# iBeacon detection by Mobile Phone Browser

Tags: html, ibeacon

Does anyone know of a script available to access the Blue tooth driver in a mobile device (Apple and Android) to see if an iBeacon is in range?

I am building an Web Page that requires location sensing capabilities for security and this would be ideal.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, as of November 2016 there are no bindings for major mobile browsers to access Bluetooth LE scan results in general, or more specifically  beacon detections.

Comment: Thats such a shame. This would have solved a massive problem. Do you know why they dont have this functionality built in?